# Multipart/form-data with multiple header and multiple content, is not generated after appending imagedata in iOS

Tags: ios, image, multipartform-data, uploading

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://example.com/avatar";
        NSLog(@"%@",urlString);
        NSString *imageName = @"hello";
        NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", @"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"avatar\"; filename=\"", imageName, @".jpg\"\r\n\""];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449MJ";
        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data"];
        [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-type"];

        NSString *contentType1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",customer_api_key];
        [request addValue:contentType1 forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

        NSString *contentType2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"app-customer"];
        [request addValue:contentType2 forHTTPHeaderField:@"Requester"];

        UIImage *image=DPView.image;
        NSData *imageData =UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1);
        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:string] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

       [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];




        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"avatar_name\"\r\n\r\n%@", NameTF.text] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"avatar_mime_type\"\r\n\r\nimage/jpg"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"customer_id\"\r\n\r\n%d",customer_id] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [request setHTTPBody:body];


        NSLog(@"Body = %@",body);

        NSString *bodydecoded =  [[NSString alloc] initWithData:body encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Bodydecoded = %@",bodydecoded);



        NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
        NSLog(@"ReturnData = %@",returnData);

        if (returnData) {


        NSString *s11=   [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
        // NSDictionary *responseDictionary1= (NSDictionary *)s11;
        NSLog(@"S11 = %@",s11);
        NSDictionary *JSON =
        [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [s11 dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]
                                        options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                          error: nil];


        NSLog(@"json finally= %@",JSON);
```

hello everyone, I am new to `IOS` so please spare me.
Here I am trying to send Image with 3 header for authorization and 3 contents in body for image related info. But as I append the `imagedata` and then decode the body, I get this output :

```
-----------------------------14737809831466499882746641449MJ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="avatar"; filename="hello.jpg"
"Content-Type: image/jpeg

ÿØÿà
```

rest of the content after image is not created or what?

but when do not append the imagedata, i get the whole form-data created normally as :

```
-----------------------------14737809831466499882746641449MJ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="avatar"; filename="hello.jpg"
"Content-Type: image/jpeg


-----------------------------14737809831466499882746641449MJ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="avatar_name"

fgh
-----------------------------14737809831466499882746641449MJ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="avatar_mime_type"

image/jpg
-----------------------------14737809831466499882746641449MJ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="customer_id"

xyz
-----------------------------14737809831466499882746641449MJ
```

and when i pass this data(in both cases), i get invalid data error from server.(obviously)

please help me, I am stuck. 
also the headers I am passing is without `boundary = %@,boundary`, is that correct. I removed it because I was getting **invalid api key error** from server.(off-course the `authorization error`)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

please use this for creating multipart form requset

```
NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Boundary-%@", [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```

don't add header in body add as follows

```
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

create body ad follows

```
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

[dicParams enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *parameterKey, NSString *parameterValue, BOOL *stop) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", parameterKey] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", parameterValue] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", strName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: %@\r\n\r\n", strMime] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:dataImage];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:body];
```

request is created and use as you want

===================

when you are adding parameters you are doing like following

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"avatar_name\"\r\n\r\n%@", NameTF.text] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

"\r\n" is the end tag form which one field is completed. 
your first parameter will start with @"\r\n--%@\r\n" which is wrong. this means one field ended and another field is started instead of that you have to do as mentioned below.

add boundary like this

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

add field name like this

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", parameterKey] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

add field value like this

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", parameterValue] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

you will get success.

Comment: Sorry but i didn't get what changes you are asking me to do in my code. Because i guess i did the exact thing. Could you please explain?

Comment: please check my updated answer i tried to explain what to change is bellow this "==================="

Comment: Thanks for your answer Moinuddin. But it didnt work for me. That wasnt my problem. My problem is Form breaks from the point i append the imageData in it. Nothing is generated after imageData. I tried the changes you mentioned. But didn't work. Sorry. i still get   `-----------------------------14737809831466499882746641449MJ 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="avatar"; filename="hello.jpg"
"Content-Type: image/jpeg 

ÿØÿà`

Comment: try to append image at last

Comment: Did it.. but then its removing the last boundary. :(  anyhow the form is not created after imageData.. can you show how your code creates a form with image.. i just need the decoded body content.. plz